# C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\mjt0uikj.exe

Tags: windows, dll

Every time I restart my pc I get this message with an OK button:
There was a problem starting
C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\mjt0uikj.exe (this is somehwere in ..32.dll)
The specified module could not be found

Im afraid it will cause problems soon enough, please let me know if you know something ...

Comment: Questions on Stack Overflow are generally expected to relate to software development. This question is more of a support request. You may have better luck asking it on Super User

Comment: See this to disinfect your PC...http://superuser.com/questions/100360/how-do-i-get-rid-of-malicious-spyware-malware-viruses-or-rootkits-from-my-pc/157533#157533

Answer (score 2):

This is a virus. If it doesn't find it then it's a good thing.

Try browsing to "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local" and delete the "Temp" directory to make sure it's all gone.

To fix the error message at startup:

1. Start menu
2. Click "Run" or type directly in the search box (Windows Vista/7)
3. "msconfig"
4. Go to the "Startup" tab
5. Find the entry matching the file and uncheck it

Finally, run Malware Bytes to clean up whatever may be left of the virus.

Comment: The file is already gone so deleting the `Temp` directory will just delete the `Temp` directory.  Running MalwareBytes is pretty much the only solution here unless they want to located the infected registry key by hand.

Comment: Yes, but these random file name are almost always accompanied by fellow oddly named files.

Answer (score 0):

Download [AutoRuns](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb963902.aspx) ("Run as Administrator"). This applications will list everything that basically starts when your computer boots. Search for that file with that path and delete it with AutoRuns. Be careful with it. If you still have problems with it, download a [LinuxLiveCD](http://www.livecdlist.com/) and boot into linux and mount the hdd. You can delete the file from there sense no windows based application with run from linux on that hdd. Permissions will not be a problem either.